# How to update CloudWatch Agent if it's not on the latest version?

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch

How to update CloudWatch Agent if it's not on the latest version?

Let's say that the CloudWatch Agent installed was version X.0. After few months, there was an update, and the latest available version of CloudWatch Agent was X.1. So, how can I proceed with updating the already installed CloudWatch Agent version?

In the user guide, I am able to find ways to 'Download and Configure the CloudWatch Agent' and other related processes but not able to find ways to update the CloudWatch Agent version.

Any prompt support in this regard will be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: have you tried `yum update amazon-cloudwatch-agent`?

Comment: Hi @Rafee - Thank you so much for your quick and prompt response. I will check on the same and keep you noted. The only command that I tried was to install it, i.e., `sudo yum install amazon-cloudwatch-agent`

Comment: @Rafee - can you please help with the command to update CloudWatch Agent version for Window Instances? Thank you so much as the above-mentioned command worked for Linux Instances.

Comment: You should read this. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html

and download the latest version. 
https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazoncloudwatch-agent/windows/amd64/latest/amazon-cloudwatch-agent.msi 

I am not sure, if this can update your Agent. If not, uninstall it, restart your machine and re-install it again.

Comment: Thanks @Rafee for sharing the related reference. I will surely check on the same and do the needful.

Answer (score 0):

As per current [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-commandline-fleet.html), installation via package manager is available for Amazon Linux only. The other systems must the respective S3 download link as described in the docs.

For those using SSM like me, only the `Uninstall and reinstall` the installation type is supported, as described in [this note](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/install-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance-fleet.html#download-CloudWatch-Agent-on-EC2-Instance-fleet):

> **ℹ️ Note**
>
> When you install or update the CloudWatch agent, only the **Uninstall and reinstall** option is supported. You can't use the **In-place update** option.